# How to make rating stars in html and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am creating an HTML web app and getting all data from API calls. I have set data into an array and display them. And there is data coming with HTML tags.

**My data set Like below;**

```
contDet = [
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_01",
      content:
        '<img src="#FOLDERPATH#logo.png" style="width:600px;height: 150px">',
    },
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_02",
      content:
        '<div style="color:black;font-size:1.3em;text-align:center;"><p>Your Opinion Is Important To Us</p></div><div style="color: black; text-align: justify;font-size: 1em;line-height: 21px;margin-left: 3%;margin-right: 3%;"><p>Please take a moment to share with us your thoughts on your visit today.</p></div>',
    },
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_03",
      content: '<ul data-role="listview" id="Review1_Ques_04">',
    },
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_06",
      content:
        '<a style="float: left;">< </a><a style="<a id="review1btn1" data-role="button" class="linkbtnPrevious"  onclick="R1goPrevious()"><B>PREVIOUS</B></a><a style="float: right;">> </a> <a id="review1btn" data-role="button"  class="linkbtnNext"  onclick="goNext()"><B>NEXT</B></a>',
    },
  ];
  contImg = [
    { idclient: "11", idlocation: "25", ImageName: "highlightedStar.png" },
    { idclient: "11", idlocation: "25", ImageName: "star.png" },
  ];
  surQue = [
    { idsurveyquestion: "22", question: "Taste of the food?" },
    { idsurveyquestion: "23", question: "Quality of the food?" },
    { idsurveyquestion: "24", question: "Speed Of delivery?" },
    { idsurveyquestion: "25", question: "The accuracy of the order?" },
    { idsurveyquestion: "26", question: "How is our service?" },
  ];
```

I need to make a 5-star rating section for each question like below.

[image: sample1]

Here I want to make a star rating for each question and need unselect star when click on the same star again.

**This is what I tried;**

```js
function getData() {
  contDet = [{
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_01",
      content: '<img src="#FOLDERPATH#logo.png" style="width:600px;height: 150px">',
    },
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_02",
      content: '<div style="color:black;font-size:1.3em;text-align:center;"><p>Your Opinion Is Important To Us</p></div><div style="color: black; text-align: justify;font-size: 1em;line-height: 21px;margin-left: 3%;margin-right: 3%;"><p>Please take a moment to share with us your thoughts on your visit today.</p></div>',
    },
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_03",
      content: '<ul data-role="listview" id="Review1_Ques_04">',
    },
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_06",
      content: '<a style="float: left;">< </a><a style="<a id="review1btn1" data-role="button" class="linkbtnPrevious"  onclick="R1goPrevious()"><B>PREVIOUS</B></a><a style="float: right;">> </a> <a id="review1btn" data-role="button"  class="linkbtnNext"  onclick="goNext()"><B>NEXT</B></a>',
    },
  ];
  contImg = [{
      idclient: "11",
      idlocation: "25",
      ImageName: "highlightedStar.png"
    },
    {
      idclient: "11",
      idlocation: "25",
      ImageName: "star.png"
    },
  ];
  surQue = [{
      idsurveyquestion: "22",
      question: "Taste of the food?"
    },
    {
      idsurveyquestion: "23",
      question: "Quality of the food?"
    },
    {
      idsurveyquestion: "24",
      question: "Speed Of delivery?"
    },
    {
      idsurveyquestion: "25",
      question: "The accuracy of the order?"
    },
    {
      idsurveyquestion: "26",
      question: "How is our service?"
    },
  ];

  //set content
  document.getElementById("Review1_Ques_01").innerHTML = contDet[0].content;
  document.getElementById("Review1_Ques_02").innerHTML = contDet[1].content;
  document.getElementById("Review1_Ques_03").innerHTML = contDet[2].content;
  document.getElementById("Review1_Ques_06").innerHTML = contDet[3].content;

  //set star image path
  //geting star img
  var starImg = contImg.filter(function(item) {
    return item.ImageName.includes("star");
  });
  // console.log(starImg);
  var starImgpath =
    "./images/" +
    starImg[0].idclient +
    "/" +
    starImg[0].idlocation +
    "/" +
    starImg[0].ImageName;

  //geting highlightedStar img
  var highlightedStarImg = contImg.filter(function(item) {
    return item.ImageName.includes("star");
  });
  console.log(starImg);
  var highlightedStarImgpath =
    "./images/" +
    highlightedStarImg[0].idclient +
    "/" +
    highlightedStarImg[0].idlocation +
    "/" +
    highlightedStarImg[0].ImageName;

  //   display question list
  $.each(surQue, function(o, que) {
    $("#Review1_Ques_04").append(
      "<li id=" + que.idsurveyquestion + ">" + que.question + "</li>"
    );
  });
}
```

```css
#Review1_Ques_04 {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="js/Test.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="javascript:getData()">
  <div id="Review1">
    <div data-role="content">
      <div id="Review1_Ques_01" class="Header-banner"></div>
      <div id="Review1_Ques_02"></div>
      <div id="Review1_Ques_03" style="margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <div id="Review1_Ques_06"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**This is the output that I have tried;**

[image: sample2]

Here I want to use my star and highlightedstar png to make the rating star like below,

```
<img  onClick="rate()"  ondblclick="uncheckAllStars()" class="star" src="./images/11/25/star.png" />
```

src should be set from the js file, and the image data also coming from API. my folder path is images->11->25.

Please help me to solve my problem.

**I need to create a section like this;**

```
<p class="ques">Taste of the food?</p>
    <div class="str">
        <img  onClick="rate()"  class="star" id="1" src="./images/11/25/star.png" />
        <img  onClick="rate()"  class="star" id="2" src="./images/11/25/star.png" />
        <img  onClick="rate()"  class="star" id="3" src="./images/11/25/star.png" />
        <img  onClick="rate()"  class="star" id="4" src="./images/11/25/star.png" />
        <img  onClick="rate()"  class="star" id="5" src="./images/11/25/star.png" />
    </div>
```

How can I create a section Like the above?

Comment: where are the stars in your attempted code?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a 1/5 star rating system in the first place? It's one of the worst ways to implement a rating system. https://hbr.org/2019/07/the-problems-with-5-star-rating-systems-and-how-to-fix-them

Comment: that's the problem. I don't know how to make a rating star for each question.

Comment: This is just a rating question survey. I need to get the user ratings for each queations.

Comment: ok @TheFool I'll check it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you

> don't know how to make a rating star for each question

The first thing you'll need is a way to make a rating for each question: here's one approach that is handled in CSS

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.rating')
.forEach(rating => {
  rating.addEventListener('input', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
  rating.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
    this.value = this.min;
    this.style.setProperty('--value', 1);
    console.log(this.value);
  });
});
```

```css
.rating {
  --dir: right;
  --fill: gold;
  --fillbg: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.15);
  --star: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 17.25l-6.188 3.75 1.641-7.031-5.438-4.734 7.172-0.609 2.813-6.609 2.813 6.609 7.172 0.609-5.438 4.734 1.641 7.031z"/></svg>');
  --stars: 5;
  --starsize: 1rem;
  --value: 1;
  --x: calc(100% * (var(--value) / var(--stars)));
  block-size: var(--starsize);
  inline-size: calc(var(--stars) * var(--starsize));
  position: relative;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
[dir="rtl"] .rating {
  --dir: left;
}
.rating::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(to var(--dir), var(--fill) 0 var(--x), var(--fillbg) 0 var(--x));
  block-size: 100%;
  mask: repeat left center/var(--starsize) var(--star);
}
.rating::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(to var(--dir), var(--fill) 0 var(--x), var(--fillbg) 0 var(--x));
  block-size: 100%;
  mask: repeat left center/var(--starsize) var(--star);
  -webkit-mask: repeat left center/var(--starsize) var(--star);
}
.rating::-moz-range-thumb {
  height: var(--starsize);
  opacity: 0;
  width: calc(var(--starsize) / 2);
}
.rating::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: var(--starsize);
  opacity: 0;
  width: calc(var(--starsize) / 2);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.rating, .rating-label {
  display: block;
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, sans-serif;
}
.rating-label {
  margin-block-end: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<label class="rating-label">Rating 1
  <input
    class="rating"
    min="1"
    max="5"
    oninput="this.style.setProperty('--value', this.value)"
    step="1"
    type="range"
    style="--value:2"
    value="2">
</label>
<label class="rating-label">Rating 2
  <input
    class="rating"
    min="1"
    max="5"
    oninput="this.style.setProperty('--value', this.value)"
    step="1"
    type="range"
    style="--value:3;--starsize:2rem"
    value="3">
</label>
```

Comment: thanks for your support. But my problem is different from this. I have to use images to may my rating star.

Comment: Simple ... change the  `--star: url(...)` to your image

Comment: @Sidath - oh, right, you have a separate image file for clients/location/name - that seems odd

Comment: yes @Bravo. It coming from API data and I sort them into variable. After That, I need to display a rating star for each question.

Comment: Question data also depends on customers. It can be changed at any time.  That's why I need to make it dynamic.

Comment: As I mention above, I have a question data list and need to display that question data and need to create a unique star rating section for each question with the image data.

Comment: You also stated `I don't know how to make a rating star for each question` - so, I thought I'd help you with that part of it

Comment: I update the question. Please look at the code below this bold phrase. `I need to create a section like this;`

Comment: Help me to solve it. I don't have good knowledge of that.

Comment: The only thing that I want is to display the data of the surQue[] array with the rating star for each question.

Comment: and also I need to send the star rating value for each question to the database. for that, if I can store that star rating value to a variable it is easy to send the data to databse.

Comment: could you please help me @bravo?